# Powershell format output of type System.Xml.XmlElement

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to construct a list of computernames which can then be used to invoke another powershell command.

Manual process:

```
$Type1Machines="Machine1","Machine2","Machine3","Machine4"
Invoke-command {Powershell.exe C:\myscript.ps1 Type1} -computername $Type1Machines
```

I already have information about the name of the "Type1" machines in an XML file (MachineInfo.xml)

```
<Servers>
<Type1>
<Machine><Name>Machine1</Name> <MachineOS>WinXP</MachineOS></Machine>
<Machine><Name>Machine2</Name> <MachineOS>WinServer2003</MachineOS></Machine>
<Machine><Name>Machine3</Name> <MachineOS>WinServer2003</MachineOS></Machine>
<Machine><Name>Machine4</Name><MachineOS>WinServer2003</MachineOS></Machine>
</Type1>
</Servers>
```

I'm trying to write a script which can pull up the list of machine name which are "Type1" and construct the below url.

> $Type1Machines="Machine1","Machine2","Machine3","Machine4"

So far, I got to the point where I can get the list of Machine names from the xml

```
    #TypeInformation will be pass as an argument to the final script
    $typeinformation = 'Type1' 
$global:ConfigFileLocation ="C:\machineinfo.xml"
$global:ConfigFile= [xml](get-content $ConfigFileLocation)

$MachineNames = $ConfigFile.SelectNodes("Servers/$typeinformation")
$MachineNames
```

Output:

```
Machine
-------
{Machine1, Machine2, Machine3, Machine4}
```

Now how do I use the above output and construct the below url?

$Type1Machines="Machine1","Machine2","Machine3","Machine4"

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want each machine name value put into array (to use with invoke-commmand):

```
[string[]]$arr = @() # declare empty array of strings
$ConfigFile.SelectNodes("/Servers/$typeInformation/Machine") | % {$arr += $_.name}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Far simpler than assigning the result to a variable and using a for loop to extract the needed info. Thanks for the help. I should start using this style of scripting.

Answer (score 3):

Accepted solution (copied):

```
[string[]]$arr = @() # declare empty array of strings
$ConfigFile.SelectNodes("/Servers/$typeInformation/Machine") | % {$arr += $_.name}
```

has this equivalent (more PowerShellish way, use .NET only when you have to):

```
$typeInformation = 'Type1'
$arr = ($ConfigFile.Servers."$typeInformation".Machine | % { $_.Name }) -join ','
```

or

```
$typeInformation = 'Type1'
$arr = ($ConfigFile | Select-Xml "/Servers/$typeInformation/Machine/Name" | % { $_.Node.'#text' }) -join ','
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code : You just forgot "*Machine*" in the Xpath query

```
#TypeInformation will be pass as an argument to the final script
$typeinformation = 'Type1' 
$global:ConfigFileLocation ="C:\machineinfo.xml"
$global:ConfigFile= [xml](get-content $ConfigFileLocation)

$Machines = $ConfigFile.SelectNodes("Servers/$typeinformation/Machine")

foreach($Machine in $Machines)
{
  Write-Host $Machine.name
}
```